# Python - How can I insert new data to pd dataframe with amending the table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Situation:
I have already built a pd table by using `pd.Dataframe` with certain column(I set)

the table is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVPXX.png]

then I realized that some of the data I scraped not in the same length
for example some students may have `sub4_grade` and `sub4_rank` or even to `sub5_grade`

but I have alr built the above table, how can I insert the new different length data to this data and to expand the columns?

thank you.

Comment: I cant see your table, what do you mean same length? `len(sub4_grade) != len(sub4_rank)`

Comment: first add a column df["sub5_grade"] = np.nan , than you can insert values

Comment: @The.B
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVPXX.png 
can you see it?

Comment: @辜乘风
but how can I insert ```sub4_grade``` between sub3_grade and sub_1 score?

Comment: do you mean switch columns' loc ?   df = df.loc[:, ['column1', 'column4', 'column3']] . Or you can switch the value